# Canon 350D autofocus problem

Tags: canon, canon-350d

I have a Canon 350D Rebel XT DSLR, one day, when i wanted to use it, the autofocus just doesn't work. The manual is doing good, but when i turn it to autofocus, it just doesn't focus. Sometimes the lcd display shows "busy", or the autofocus indicator just kept on blinking.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Photo SE. It's going to be very hard for someone to answer this question without knowing some more information, if at all. Can you indicate which lens you are using, and whether the AF works with other lenses? That will help to determine whether the problem lies with the camera or the lens, but beyond that your best bet would be to take the camera to a specialist.

Comment: Also, to be clear: what are you trying to focus on, and in what conditions? It sounds like it worked before and suddenly stopped -- is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Two main possibilities, the AF system in the camera for identifying proper focus may be shot or the AF motor in the lens may be shot.  If you have more than one lens, switch lenses and see if you still have a problem.  If multiple lenses can't focus, the problem is probably in your camera, possibly the AF sensor is not functioning.

If only the one lens doesn't work, them there is likely a problem with the AF motor in the lens and it would need to be repaired or replaced.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled over the same problem, my EOS 350D would not autofocus when in Program mode (P), but OK when in Auto mode. It would just focus in and out, and not stop at the right focal point. No matter which lens. 
My solution, after cleaning contacts and playing with all Custons Fn., was to push the AF point selector button (rear, top right), thus getting a bracket-picture in the LCD. By turning the main dial  wheel (behind shutter button), and placing the pointer in the bracket in the middle, the focusing works.
Hope this might solve someones problems.

Comment: That probably means that the outer focus points aren't working correctly.  This could be because the lens is decentered, because the autofocus sensor is misaligned, because of dust blocking the autofocus sensor, or because you're using a teleconverter.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the electrical contacts on both the lens and the body a gentle cleaning. If either side is dirty you may not be getting a proper connection.